# Using generalized mixed models in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression, mixed-models

I'm trying to run a logistic regression but for a within-subject design so I ended up using a generalized mixed model (`glmer` and `lme` functions in R). There is one predictor (with 3 conditions) and a binary outcome coded as 0 or 1.

I was wondering if anyone had advice on which model is better to use and why.

I'm also having trouble interpreting the output, and the summary seems to be leaving out one of the three conditions in my predictor. When I run the code below:

```
D1_data <- read.table("data", header = TRUE, sep = ",") 
print(D1_data)

library(nlme)
model <- lme(output ~ condition, data = D1_data, random = ~1|participant)

anova(model)
summary(model)


log.model <- glmer(output ~ condition + (1|participant), data=D1_data, family=binomial(link=logit))

summary(log.model)
anova(log.model)
```

The summary of only includes the first two conditions (in both instances) for example:

```
Fixed effects:
               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)       40.03     427.04   0.094    0.925
condition1   -39.63     427.04  -0.093    0.926
condition2   -37.07     427.04  -0.087    0.931
```

Even though there should be a third condition. What is the issue here?

Comment: "Which model is better and why" and how to interpret the output is statistics, not programming, so the question will be much more at home at stats.stackexchange.com rather than here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Generally, when you have `k` levels of a categorical variable, the first level is considered the "reference level", and that is what the intercept is fit to. All the other estimates are in comparison to the reference level.

Comment: This question is very broad (understanding what model to use, why, and to interpret output)... Probably too broad for stats.stackexchange.com. I'd suggest checking out these GLMM resources as a place to start: http://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/ecostats_chap.html